# Struts2 - getting variable from complex structure

Tags: variables, struts2

I have a JSP, here the snippet:

```
<s:set var="tmpIdObj"
       value="form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj"/>

<s:set var="c6" 
       value="form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[#tmpIdObj].confermata"/>
```

I would like to write all in one row, avoiding to create the tmpIdObj variable, as following:

```
<s:set var="c6"
       value="form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj].confermata"/>
```

i tried to use singlequotes or other struts sintaxes, but i'm not able to arrange it.
I'm looking for the working syntax.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to make anybody look at that in your JSP? It's unmaintainable.

Comment: because the people who created this big project always did it in this way and i have to strictly follow their coding standards...

Comment: What type is your `idObj`? And what type is key in `form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione`?

Comment: `datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione` is a HashMap<Long, Object>. `Confermata` is a boolean property of the Map value. `idObj` is a Long.

Comment: Your syntax looks good and it should work. But as Dave said it's unmaintainable. And if it works with `tmpIdObj` variable then why do you want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AN EXAMPLE BEFORE GETTING INSANE :**

The given code is too complicated, so I created a bean for testing purpose :

```java
package fr.hbonjour.formulaires.actions;

public class PlaceBean {

    private String name;

    private String adress;

    private Long index;

    public PlaceBean()
    {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public PlaceBean(Long id, String name, String adress)
    {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setAdress(adress);
        this.setIndex(id);
    }

        ... (getters and setters)

}
```

Then I tried this :

```xml
<s:bean name="fr.hbonjour.formulaires.actions.PlaceBean" var="bean" />

<s:set var="bean.name" value="places[places[0].index].name" />

    <!-- Prompt the name from the created bean -->
<td><s:property value="bean.name"/></td>
```

places[0].index returns a Long value, and places[places[0].index].name a String value. Here are the values of my list :

```
0   GABRIEL
1   WU
```

So places[places[0].index].name= places[0].name = GABRIEL. Indeed the `<s:property />` tag displays `GABRIEL`.

A more tricky example :

```xml
<s:bean name="fr.hbonjour.formulaires.actions.PlaceBean" var="bean" />
<s:iterator status="stat" value="places">
    <tr>
        <s:set var="bean.name" value="places[places[#stat.index].index].name" />
        <td><s:property value="bean.name"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

So... for #stat.index = 0 for example, places[places[#stat.index].index].name = places[places[0].index].name = places[0].name = GABRIEL. This code returns the following values :

```
GABRIEL
WU
```

**LET'S CHECK!**

form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj].confermata

We saw that if `#k.index` was an iterator index and `lista[#k.index].idObj` returned a Long value, `lista[#k.index].idObj` worked (`places[#stat.index].index` worked in our example).

Wa saw that if `lista[#k.index].idObj` returned a Long value, `datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[lista[#k.index].idObj].confermata` worked (`places[places[#stat.index].index].name` worked in our example).

**SO ?**

I suggest you check step by step, as I did in my example, every value of the expression. Because nobody will be able to exactly re-make you test case. Maybe you should especially check the `form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid]` part of the expression. I don't doubt you will manage to find the answer that way.

But anyway, it's soooo ugly. Good luck.

Comment: ...well, since you were right, about the complexity, i left the code as it was, i mean using tmpObj. In this way it is clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Force OGNL evaluation by using `%{}`

```
<s:set var="c6"
       value="form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[%{form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj}].confermata"/>
```

Copy, paste, run and come back here to post the output:

```
  <div style="border: 5px solid red; width: 100%;">

    form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj: [
    <s:property value="form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj" />]

    form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[%{form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj}].confermata: [
    <s:property value="form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[%{form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[#qid].lista[#k.index].idObj}].confermata" />]

    form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[%{#qid}].lista[%{#k.index}].idObj].confermata: [
    <s:property value="form.datiVersioneQuoteAssegnazione[form.dati.assegnazioniAnnualitaAtto[%{#qid}].lista[%{#k.index}].idObj].confermata" />]

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried it but it doesn't work. `qid` is another variable set, `k` is the counter of an iterator...